# How do I get AttachmentSelection for an Outlook message in the Preview Pane (VBA)?

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, preview-pane

I'm trying to use AttachmentSelection as part of a workaround to drag-and-drop Outlook attachments into Access, but the roadblock I've run into is that Explorer.AttachmentSelection doesn't give me anything, and I can only use Inspector.AttachmentSelection on emails open in their own window (there's no active Inspector for an item in the Preview Pane) - and the source email folder is always in preview mode.

So okay, fine, I tried using GetInspector on the current MailItem, and although that Inspector object seems otherwise fine and points to the correct email, AttachmentSelection is **still **empty (but fine if the email is open in a separate window).

Code snippet (all variables have been declared with early binding; I tried late binding on MailItem and Inspector objects, but it made no difference):

```
If olApp is Nothing Then Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Set olExp = olApp.ActiveExplorer
Set olSel = olExp.Selection

Set olMsg = olSel(1)
Set olInsp = olMsg.GetInspector
Set olAttach = olInsp.AttachmentSelection

AttachCount = olAttach.Count

If AttachCount > 0 Then 
     [Loop through attachments]
EndIf
```

If the email is open in a separate window, AttachCount is the number of attachments selected; if it's in the Preview Pane, it's zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.ActiveInspector` instead. Is it showing the attachment preview at the time of the call? If not, Outlook won't think it is selected.

For the reading pane, you need to use `Explorer.AttachmentSelection`:

[image]

Comment: GetInspector was my workaround *because* ActiveInspector didn't work for Preview Pane emails - they don't have inspectors at all. (olApp.Inspectors.Count = 0)

Also, whether or not the attachment was being previewed made no difference, but even if it did it's not a workable solution because I can't really control how other people will use it.

Comment: For the reading pane, you need to use `Explorer.AttachmentSelection` - which works fine (see OutlookSpy screenshot above).

Comment: Explorer.AttachmentSelection works if I click on the attachment into preview mode, and it continues to work even if I exit the preview. But if I just click and drag from the preview pane, I get nothing.  

It also looks like the same limitation exists on emails that are open in their own window, whereas Inspector.AttachmentSelection works on those without preview mode.  

I'm trying to make this intuitive as possible, so I'm trying to get drag-and-drop to work without caveats.

Comment: That's just how OOM works I am afraid...